# Sql Server 2008: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get `03-01` as the result `@startmonth` but I keep getting

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

```
DECLARE @startmonth date, @newdate date

SELECT @newdate    = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(DATE, '2012-02-29'))
SELECT @startmonth = CONVERT(DATE,RIGHT(RTRIM(CONVERT(DATE,@newdate)),5))

print @startmonth
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the result as `03-01` then the variable cannot be of `date` type. Change the `@startmonth` datatype to `varchar`

Also there are few unwanted codes in your query. Try this.

```
DECLARE @startmonth VARCHAR(6),@newdate    DATE

SELECT @newdate = Dateadd(DAY, 1,'2012-02-29')

SELECT @startmonth = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(15), @newdate, 110), 5)

Print @startmonth
```